# Get rid of mistaken peaks in an iOS graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, nsarray, smoothing

I have a `NSArray` of float values, and I represent this array in a graph, it looks this way:

[image]

As you see, there are peak values...I can easily count them when I look at the graph (11 peaks), but if I look at my array values, there are some "false" peaks, see next picture:

[image]

**My question is**: How can I get rid of such mistaken peaks, in order to draw a smoother graph?

I want to have an array with peak values at about the same interval and with increased values, in order to highlight them, something like this:

[image]

PS: Values in my graph array are always changing, but the graph looks almost the same.

Comment: First of all, you have to describe how (without computer, but just with your "brain") detect what is a false peak. Then, we can think about how detect them by code. For example, does 2 peaks needs to be separated by "4/5" values?

Comment: I just highlighted all values that are bigger than its neighbours, and observed the values that are located at about the same interval (not necessary between 4-5 items), and all the peaks between them, are useless. I understand it's a bit hard to figure out what I mean..I'm doing my best to explain :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Lowpass and Highpass filters from [AccelerometerGraph](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007410-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) project, provided on Apple iOS documentation. Now my graph looks much better:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Split your array into subintervals and find maxima in those.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little?

Comment: If You split the array into intervals of say length 4 You can take maximum value from the interval and mark it as a peak in the whole array, take next interval and mark another peak, and another and another...
Hope that's what You meant.

Comment: PS. The tricky part would be to determine the length of the interval, in Your case it would need to be 6 from the second picture.
My guess would be to get index of the first peak and set the interval length to this +1 (peak needs two neighbouring values)

Comment: I get it now but please add some more substance to your answer - and not just in the comments

Comment: addition: maybe: to figure out what is a peak you could look at the first (e.g.)10 values and find the max (that is considerably larger than all the rest) and based on where the max is you'd define the interval length